# How to combine (comma-separated) row values in a single column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame. How can I convert the first data frame into the second one?

It tried the following but it keeps throwing `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`
`res_df = book_df.pivot(index='book_id', columns='field', values='field_value')` I think this happens because `book_id=1` has multiple `title` values (X and Y). I would like to comma separate these cases.

**Input**

```
| id | book_id | field  | field_value  |
|----|---------|--------|--------------|
| 1  | 1       | title  | X            |
| 2  | 1       | title  | Y            |
| 3  | 1       | bsn    | 999          |
| 4  | 2       | title  | Harry Potter |
| 5  | 3       | title  | Hello World  |
| 6  | 3       | author | John Doe     |
```

**Expected output**

```
| id | book_id | title        | bsn | author   |
|----|---------|--------------|-----|----------|
| 1  | 1       | X,Y          | 999 |          |
| 2  | 2       | Harry Potter |     |          |
| 3  | 3       | Hello World  |     | John Doe |
```

Comment: what happes to id `4,5,6` ??

Comment: Please ignore ‘id’. It is about the other columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pivot was nearly correct. I used [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and added a string join with the `aggfunc` argument

```
(book_df.pivot_table(index='book_id', columns='field', values='field_value', aggfunc=','.join, fill_value='')
  .reset_index()
  .rename_axis(None, axis=1)[['book_id','title','bsn','author']])
```

Out:

```
   book_id         title  bsn    author
0        1           X,Y  999          
1        2  Harry Potter               
2        3   Hello World       John Doe
```

Comment: Any idea how can I get rid of the hardcoded column names in `rename_axis`? Only `book_id` column is static, therefore does not change. All other columns are dynamic...

Comment: The selection list `[['book_id'...]]` after `rename_axis` sorts the columns in the way your desired output was sorted. Without them only the order of the columns change. You can leave them out, if the order of the columns doesn't matter.

Comment: Can I use `aggfunc` to convert it to array instead of comma separated string? `['X', 'Y']` instead of `'X,Y'`

Comment: Yes. You can use `aggfunc=np.array` to convert aggregations with multiple values to an `np.array`.  Or `aggfunc=list` to aggregate every value into a list.